# Alamofire Issue

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm creating a project that involves Stripe. I realized that by using Swift, I need to use Alamorefire, not AFNetworking. So I updated my pod file by deleting AFNetworking and installing Alamofire instead. After I installed Alamofire and followed a Stripe integration tutorial on YouTube, I went to run the project and now have dozens of errors. I put code already in one of my View Controller's, per the video. I'm not exactly sure what I need to do to fix this, since I am also new at coding. What do I do? Attached is a screenshot of the type of errors I'm getting, in addition to the video tutorial for Stripe.

Thanks in advance!

[Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9uts0A_4a8)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What version of Swift and Alamofire are you using in your project? If you haven't updated your project to Swift 3 and pulled the latest Alamofire stuff (which is Swift 3) it could cause some problems.

Comment: I just did this and still have an issue.